# Oracle Transaction Rollback doesn't work (Insert + ArrayBinding + Returning)

Tags: c#, oracle

One of my customers is facing a strange issue when Oracle Transaction.Rollback doesn't work.

It appears the following thing must be used:

- Transaction or TransactionScope
- A PL/SQL (BEGIN END)
- ArrayBinding with at least 2 items
- The returning statement

Both items are still inserted in the database even if a rollback have been called.

Anyone have a clue why such behavior could happen?

```
using (var connection = new OracleConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["OracleCodeFirstEntities"].ConnectionString))
{
    connection.Open();
    var transaction = connection.BeginTransaction();

    using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
    {
        command.BindByName = true;

        command.CommandText = @"
BEGIN
INSERT  INTO ""SYSTEM"".""EF_0104"" (""IntColumn"") VALUES(:P_0) RETURNING ""ID"" INTO :ZZZOUTPUT_0;
END;
";
        int[] array = new int[] { 1, 2 };

        var param1 = command.CreateParameter();
        param1.ParameterName = "P_0";
        param1.DbType = DbType.Int32;
        param1.Value = array;


        var param2 = command.CreateParameter();
        param2.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
        param2.ParameterName = "ZZZOUTPUT_0";
        param2.DbType = DbType.Int32;
        param2.Value = array;

        command.Parameters.Add(param1);
        command.Parameters.Add(param2);

        command.ArrayBindCount = array.Length;
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

    transaction.Rollback();
}
```

**Adding additional information**

> If there is an exception before transaction.Rollback()

No, the rollback is done successfully without error.

If I do it with only one item in the array, the rollback happen, if I do it without the returning statement, the rollback happen, but if this exact scenario happens, the rollback doesn't happen.

> which db provider are you using

I have used Oracle.ManagedDataAccess (v4.121.2.0)

> Could the issue be that auto commit is enabled?

I don't think this is the issue since if I remove one of the variants, the rollback works correctly.

> Have you turned on oracle tracing

I will check this tomorrow; I'm not very familiar with Oracle right now.

Comment: That is strange. Have you turned on oracle tracing and see what tkprof shows?

Comment: You'll also want to check for exceptions.  If there is an exception before `transaction.Rollback()` it won't be called.  Protip: your transaction object also needs to be in a `using` statement.

Comment: which db provider are you using? the one from Oracle is often better .net built in one

Comment: I have to confess no knowledge of c#. However, may other languages have configuration options, and these often include auto commit. Could the issue be that auto commit is enabled?

Comment: As far as I can tell from my own tests, if you use ArrayBinding (`DbCommand.ArrayBindCount` field), then transaction control commands such as `COMMIT` and `ROLLBACK` are not supported. There is a brief mention in the [Oracle Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/win.112/e23174/extenRest.htm#ODPNT451) that those same transaction commands are not supported for ".NET stored procedures" and my guess is that ArrayBinding also falls into that category.